# Get encrypted text as NSString instead of NSData

Tags: ios, aes

How i can get encrypted data as string instead of NSData object in Objectice -C?
I need to send this encrypted text to >net method and decryption procedures are handles in .Net code.
Or anyone can help me to encrypt a text in iOS and decrypt it in >net ?

Adding from comment - Zaph
I am using this code:

```
StringEncryption *crypto = [[StringEncryption alloc] init];
NSData *_secretData = [SearchKey dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
CCOptions padding = kCCOptionPKCS7Padding;
NSData *key = [_key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *encryptedData = [crypto encrypt:_secretData key:key padding:&padding];
```

I need to send encryptedData to .Net. But i dnt know how to send NSData to .Net method , so i tried to convert this encryptedData to `NSString`, unfortunately it gives me nil. I tried with base64EncodedStringWithOptions,its also giving error when i am decrypting.

Comment: Sure, help is available here. Writing code is not. Study, research, write the best you can. If it doesn't work come back here with the problem code and help should be available.

Comment: Data encryption produces 8-bit bytes, not ASCII characters. As such some encoding is needed, generally that is Base64.

Comment: Encrypted data must be dealt with as 8-bit bytes, not conventional characters.  If you attempt to treat the data as characters you inevitably corrupt it and it will not decipher.  If you need a character string for transmission, encode the 8-bit bytes into Base64.

Comment: What is the StringEncryption class? What .new class? What is not shown is the mode and if CBC (it should be using CBC move) the iv and the key length. The key should not be a string (passwords) and the key should be the  correct length. So how are these things handled in StringEncryption and .net?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert NSData to base 64 string. 
For iOS 7,  NSData has these two methods: (direct quotes from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-SW37) doc)

`base64EncodedDataWithOptions` : Create a Base-64, UTF-8 encoded NSData from the receiver's contents using the given options.

`base64EncodedStringWithOptions` : Create a Base-64 encoded NSString from the receiver's contents using the given options.

Comment: I am using this code      StringEncryption *crypto = [[StringEncryption alloc] init] ;
 NSData *_secretData = [SearchKey dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 CCOptions padding =kCCOptionPKCS7Padding;
 NSData *encryptedData = [crypto encrypt:_secretData key:[_key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] padding:&padding];
and I need to send encryptedData to .Net. But i dnt know how to send NSData to .Net method , so i tried to convert this encryptedData to NSString, unfortunately it gives me nil.i  tried with base64EncodedStringWithOptions,its also giving error when i am decrypting....

Comment: Added comment to question for formatting and question continuity.